# Json-парсер для Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, синтаксический-анализ

Чем парсить Json? Есть какие нибудь нормальные и легкие в освоении парсеры Json?

Comment: Сборник компонентов для Delphi по JSON и другим темам: https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/awesome-delphi#xmljsonyaml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Все ведь на [официальном сайте JSONа](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html) перечислены:

- [JSON delphi library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/)
- [Delphi Web Utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/)
- [json-superobject](http://code.google.com/p/superobject/)
- [tiny-json](http://code.google.com/p/tiny-json/)

Comment: json-superobject  оказался довольно простым и удобным спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
uses
  Data.DBXJSON

//..
var
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"name","value"}') as TJSONObject;
  ShowMessage(JSONObject.Get('name').JsonValue.Value)
```

но не хочет парсить данные типа {123:"value"}
написал такой "патч":

```
class function TJSONObject.ParsePair(const Br: TJSONByteReader; const Parent: TJSONObject): Integer;
var
  Pair: TJSONPair;
  CommaPos: Integer;
begin
  Pair := TJSONPair.Create;
  Parent.AddDescendant(Pair);

//  CommaPos := ParseString(Br, Pair); /////////////////////////////////////////
{ Заміна щоб бачило рядки типу {33:33}
  ConsumeWhitespaces(Br);
  if Br.PeekByte in [Ord('0')..Ord('9')] then
    CommaPos := ParseNumber(Br, Pair)
  else
    CommaPos := ParseString(Br, Pair);
{/}

  if CommaPos > 0 then
  begin
    ConsumeWhitespaces(Br);
    if Br.Empty then
      Exit(-Br.Offset);
    if Br.PeekByte <> Ord(':') then
      Exit(-Br.Offset);
    Br.ConsumeByte;
    ConsumeWhitespaces(Br);
    CommaPos := ParseValue(Br, Pair);
  end;
  Result := CommaPos;
end;
```

Просто замени соответствующую функу (можешь сохранить в другом файле)

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Delphi 2010 присутствует встроенная поддержка json (модуль Data.DBXJSON) в рамках технологии dbExpress, также в дополнение к уже перечисленным библиотекам, появилась еще одна от [Andreas Hausladen](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/), автора IDE Tools для Delphi: [Json Data Objects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects), поддерживаются версии начиная с 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Результата стоило бы стыдиться, но меня не устроил ни один из имевшихся вариантов, поэтому я написал свой: https://github.com/badunius/myJSON

UPD: Не устроила прежде всего громоздкость, требующая для работы со вложенностью либо заводить орду переменных, либо выстраивать чересчур нечитаемые цепочки. Приведение типов хоть и прогрессивно, но тоже читабельности не добавляет. Я привык работать с JSON в JS, поэтому мне была важна максимальная сходность синтаксиса.

Ах да, и главным требованием, конечно, была совместимость с Delphi 7, потому что я всё ещё ею пользуюсь.

Comment: Пожалуй, вам стоит подробнее описать, чем именно вас не устроили имеющиеся варианты и чем хороша ваша версия. Пока пост скорее рекламного характера, чем информационного.

Comment: почему удаляются табы и переносы строк сразу со всей строки? а если одно из свойств будет строкой содержащей эти символы?

Comment: @Grundy насколько я помню, в JS-строках перенос строки, возврат каретки и табуляция передаются сочетаниями символов \n, \r и \t соответственно. То есть, когда я в блокноте набираю \t, он не превращается автоматически в $09. Соответственно $09 и $20 используются только для форматирования текста. VS Code, например, разорванную переносом строку-значение в JSON валидной не считает.

Comment: @badunius, да, [действительно](https://www.json.org/json-ru.html). json более строг :-)

Answer (score 0):

В последних версиях Delphi, есть встроенная библиотека [JSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.JSON)